# Continue to run thread?

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading, algorithm

I have a service and a thread inside it. I want to only keep running the thread while my shared preference variable is true. How can I accomplish this? I want something like this:

```
//My Service

while(preferences.getBoolean("doIkeepRunningThread", false) == true){ //User wants me to continue to run this thread

thread.continueToRun() //Not a real method, I just made it up to show what I want

 }
```

### Basically, I want to say, "as long as this variable (shared prefs) is true, keep running this thread, but as soon as its false, stop the thread."

Everything is in a service.

The reason I want to implement this is because I have a settings screen where **the user can choose to stop my thread**. My problem is when the thread is currently running, and then the user decides to stop it, it will continue running.

P.S. The service is never ending, and is constantly collecting data.

Comment: My thread will contain a listener that is always listening.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread in your `Service`? One constantly collecting data and another one doing something else?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Yes I have two threads, and I run them both at the same time.

Comment: One solution is to put an appropriate `while` loop in your thread's `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)
{
   if(preferences.getBoolean("doIkeepRunningThread", false)==false)
   {
      thread.stop();
      break;
   }
}
```